# jquery delegate not binding to all elements when used with innerHtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I have the following  template:

```
<p id="myWrapper" innerHtml="{{myHtmlValue}}"></p>
```

And on my typescript i have the following

```
apiCallIAmDoing.subscribe(response => {
   this.myHtmlValue = 'bla <a class="val1">test1</a>  bla <a class="val2">test2</a>';
   $('#myWrapper').delegate('a', 'click', event => {
         console.log('test binding');
   });
})
```

for val2 it works, however for val1 it does not. What am i missing?

Plunk:
https://plnkr.co/edit/LU1QiaH7uX0lOI2tOFKr?p=preview

Comment: *`delegate`*? In 2017? :-) Consider: http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler In any case, please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, since of course `delegate`/`on` isn't fundamentally broken. Ideally, make it a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: Your example has mis-matched quotes. I'm surprised it's working at all

Comment: You should not use double-quotes `"` to surround your HTML code.

Comment: jQuery `.delegate()` is deprecated. Start using `.on()` instead. Also, as a rule of thumb, avoid adding event handlers inside event handlers, most of the time this does not produce desirable results.

Comment: regarding the quotes. merely a mistype when simplifying the example.

Comment: migrating to on does not solve this.   And i tried moving the biding to ngAfterViewInit however it then did not bind either of them

Comment: added plunk to example

Comment: Of course does moving to `.on()` not solve this. That just moves to the non-deprecated API function. The event binding must occur after `#myWrapper` DIV is added to the page. Alternatively you can delegate from the document level, like so: `$(document).on('click', '#myWrapper a', function() { ... })`, in this case it does not matter when you set up the binding.

Answer (score 0):

try using on instead, like this:

```
   $('#myWrapper').on('click', 'a', function() {
         console.log('test binding');
   });
```

Comment: If i do this inside the subscribe as above it stilld doesn't bind to both.  I also tried moving this into ngAfterViewInit but at that point none of them are bound.

Comment: Why aren't you creating the <a> tag beforehand and then filling it up with the values you need afterwards? I don't that the innerHtml property is the right place to do this. Please provide more code so we can see the structure and the logic of what you are doing.

Comment: i'm getting a string from the api call and dynamically adding the <a> tag so i have to use innerHtml